# Ajax reload frame only works once

Tags: php, ajax, reload

I have a timetable on my website. The user can select multiple times. The selected time is inserted into the database and the button turns from green to red, so the user know it's disabled.

I want to do this with only a reload of div. 
It does work but it work only once, when pushing the button for the second time the div doesn't refresh / reload.

Update database / refresh;

```
    $('.updateTime').click(function(){
        var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
                }
            }
        };


        var uniqueId = $(this).attr('id');
        var sdate = getUrlParameter('date');

        $.ajax({
            url: './ajax/reservation_insert_times.php',
            type: 'POST', 
            data: {
                uniqueId :uniqueId, sdate :sdate
            },

            success: function(mydiv){
            $("#result").load(location.href+ ' #mydiv');
            }

        });
    });
```

The code for generating the times

```
    <div class="row" id="result">

        <?          
        $result = array();  
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM reservation_times WHERE datum = '" . db_escape($_GET['date']) . "' ");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $result[] = $row['time']; 
        }           
    ?>
    <?
    $timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")." 12:00");

    for ($i=0;$i<=32;$i++) {

        $time = date('H:i', $timestamp);
        $time .= ' UUR';

        if (in_array($time, $result)) {
            $color = "background-color:red !important";
        }
        else $color = "";

        $timestamp += 15 * 60; 

        if (isset($checked) && $checked !='') { $color = 'background-color: red;';}?>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2" id="mydiv">
                <button type="button" id="<?=$time;?>" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-sm text-center" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:10px; <?=$color;?>" onclick="" <? if (isset($checked) && $checked !='') { echo 'disabled';}?>>
            <?=$time;?>
                </button>
            </div>

        <? } ?>       
    </div>
```

The code for the reservation_availablity.php call:

```
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM reservation_times WHERE time = '".$uniqueId."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) {
    $remove = $db->query("DELETE FROM reservation_times WHERE time = '".$uniqueId."'");
} else {
    if (isset($uniqueId) && $uniqueId !='') :
        $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO reservation_times (time, datum)
    VALUES ('".$uniqueId."', '".$newDate."')");
    endif;
}
```

Comment: It is because the new div that you insert into your DOM is not listened by your first JavaScript. So when the user click on it, nothing happen. You have to listen to it again when it is inserted. Would be like that:

```JavaScript
success: function(mydiv){
    $("#result").load(location.href+ ' #mydiv');
    // listen to "#mydiv"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you `success` method of your `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
        url: './ajax/reservation_insert_times.php',
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {
            uniqueId :uniqueId, sdate :sdate
        },

        success: function(mydiv){
            $("#result").html(mydiv);    
        }

    });
```

You are sending an `ajax` to get new content but then in `success` method instead of loading new content received as `ajax` response you are again loading the content of the same div. That's why it is working for the first time but will remain unchanged next time onwards.

```
//Wrong
$("#result").load(location.href+ ' #mydiv'); 

// Correct
$("#result").html(mydiv);
```

So, now whenever this `ajax` send to the server, it will update the content of `div#result`. And to allow user to manually refresh the content of this div as and when desired then you will have to call this `ajax` upon click of a button labled as `Refresh Timetable`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying about the loading the content in the same div, but how do I get the 'Refresh Timetable'?

When I use $("#result").html(mydiv); the div disappears completely after I clicked on one of the times in the timetable.